# Excel and VBA Crashing Midway Through Macro

Tags: vba, excel, text

I am new to VBA and hoping for some help implementing a user-defined function. I would really appreciate any help!

**Context**: I am trying to import a batch of fixed-width text files into separate Excel workbooks. The text files all have the same fields and format. I know the length of each field. Currently, I am trying to get my VBA code to work for a single text file.

**Issue**: As I'm new to VBA, I looked for existing code. I found [Chip Pearson's ImportFixedWidth function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ImportingFixedWidth.aspx), [edited one error found by another StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198781/trying-to-use-vba-to-import-fixed-width-text-files-to-excel), and have been trying to implement my TestImport function (see below) ever since. (*Note that the ... is just for the sake of brevity - not actually included in the code.)

```
Sub TestImport()
Dim L As Long
L = ImportFixedWidth("/Users/gitanjali/Desktop/CAC06075test.txt", _
    Range("A1"), _
    False, _
    vbNullString, _ 
    "1,5|2,45|3,3|4,45|5,45|6,45|7,60|8,15|9,11|10,60| _
                 11,60|12,10|13,5|14,5|15,3|16,3|17,3|18,3|19,11|20,10| 
                 ...190,250|191,250")
End Sub
```

See the ImportFixedWidth function at the end of this post.

I then tried to run the macro within the workbook, but it crashes VBA and Excel every time. The first field is imported (not the other 190) into the open workbook, but the program stops responding and has to be quit.

**Debugging**: The code compiles. I don't get any errors when I step through either the TestImport or ImportFixedWidth code. I've tried running the macro on both a Mac and a Windows PC (it crashes on both). And the first field is imported properly before the program crashes, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

**Question**: I'm at a loss for next steps in terms of debugging. Are there any obvious errors in my implementation? What would my next logical debugging step be?

```
Function ImportFixedWidth(FileName As String, _
    StartCell As Range, _
    IgnoreBlankLines As Boolean, _
    SkipLinesBeginningWith As String, _
    ByVal FieldSpecs As String) As Long
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ImportFixedWidth
' By Chip Pearson, chip@cpearson.com www.cpearson.com
' Date: 27-August-2011
' Compatible with 64-bit platforms.
'
' This function imports text from a fixed field width file.
' FileName is the name of the file to import. StartCell is
' the cell in which the import is to begin. IgnoreBlankLines
' indicates what to do with empty lines in the text file. If
' IgnoreBlankLines is False, an empty row will appear in the
' worksheet. If IgnoreBlankLines is True, no empty row will
' appear in the worksheet. SkipLinesBeginingWith indicates
' what character, if any, at the begining of the line indicates
' that the line should not be imported, such as fpr providing for
' comments within the text file. FieldSpecs indicates how to
' map the data into cells. It is a string of the format:
'           start,length|start,length|start,length...
' where each 'start' is the character position of the field
' in the text line and each 'length' is the length of the field.
' For example, if FieldSpecs is
'           1,8|9,3|12,5
' indicates the first field starting in position 1 for a
' length of 8, the second field starts in position 9 for a
' length of 3, and finally a field beginning in position 12
' for a length of 5. Fields can be in any order and may
' overlap.
' You can specify a number format for the field which will
' be applied to the worksheet cell. This format should not
' be in quotes and should follow the length element. For example,
'       2,8|9,3,@|12,8,dddd dd-mmm-yyyy
' This specifies that no formatting will be applied to column 2,
' the Text (literal) format will be applied to column 9, and
' the format 'dddd dd-mmm-yyyy' will be applied to column 12.
'
' The function calls ImportThisLine, which should return
' True to import the text from the file, or False to skip
' the current line.
' This function returns the number of records imported if
' successful or -1 if an error occurred.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim FINdx As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim R As Range
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim S As String
Dim RecCount As Long
Dim FieldInfos() As String
Dim FInfo() As String
Dim N As Long
Dim T As String
Dim B As Boolean

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
On Error GoTo EndOfFunction:

If Dir(FileName, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
    ' file not found
    ImportFixedWidth = -1
    Exit Function
End If

If Len(FieldSpecs) < 3 Then
    ' invalid FieldSpecs
    ImportFixedWidth = -1
    Exit Function
End If

If StartCell Is Nothing Then
    ImportFixedWidth = -1
    Exit Function
End If

Set R = StartCell(1, 1)
C = R.Column
FNum = FreeFile

Open FileName For Input Access Read As #FNum
' get rid of any spaces
FieldSpecs = Replace(FieldSpecs, Space(1), vbNullString)
' omit double pipes ||
N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, "||", vbBinaryCompare)
Do Until N = 0
    FieldSpecs = Replace(FieldSpecs, "||", "|")
    N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, "||", vbBinaryCompare)
Loop
' omit double commas
N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, ",,", vbBinaryCompare)
Do Until N = 0
    FieldSpecs = Replace(FieldSpecs, ",,", ",")
    N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, ",,", vbBinaryCompare)
Loop

' get rid of leading and trailing | characters, if necessary
If StrComp(Left(FieldSpecs, 1), "|", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
    FieldSpecs = Mid(FieldSpecs, 2)
End If
If StrComp(Right(FieldSpecs, 1), "|", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
    FieldSpecs = Left(FieldSpecs, Len(FieldSpecs) - 1)
End If

Do
    ' read the file
    Line Input #FNum, S
    If SkipLinesBeginningWith <> vbNullString And _
            StrComp(Left(Trim(S), Len(SkipLinesBeginningWith)), _
            SkipLinesBeginningWith, vbTextCompare) Then
        If Len(S) = 0 Then
            If IgnoreBlankLines = False Then
                Set R = R(2, 1)
            Else
                ' do nothing
            End If
        Else
            ' allow code to change the FieldSpecs values

            If FieldSpecs = vbNullString Then
                ' FieldSpecs is empty. Do nothing, don't import.
            Else
                If ImportThisLine(S) = True Then
                    FieldInfos = Split(FieldSpecs, "|")
                    C = R.Column
                    For FINdx = LBound(FieldInfos) To UBound(FieldInfos)
                        FInfo = Split(FieldInfos(FINdx), ",")
                        R.EntireRow.Cells(1, C).Value = Mid(S, CLng(FInfo(0)), CLng(FInfo(1)))
                        C = C + 1
                    Next FINdx
                    RecCount = RecCount + 1
                End If
                Set R = R(2, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ' no skip first char
    End If

Loop Until EOF(FNum)

EndOfFunction:
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ImportFixedWidth = RecCount
Else
    ImportFixedWidth = -1
End If
Close #FNum
End Function

Private Function ImportThisLine(S As String) As Boolean

Dim N As Long
Dim NoImportWords As Variant
Dim T As String
Dim L As Long

NoImportWords = Array("page", "product", "xyz")
For N = LBound(NoImportWords) To UBound(NoImportWords)
    T = NoImportWords(N)
    L = Len(T)
    If StrComp(Left(S, L), T, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ImportThisLine = False
        Exit Function
    End If
Next N
ImportThisLine = True
End Function
```

Comment: how many fields?  it may be easier to use the string parse() command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is your "field definition string"  `"1,5|2,45|3,3|4,45|5,45|6,45|7,60|8,15|9,11|10,60| _`  ... the first digit of each pair is the starting position and the second is the length ... so it should be `"1,5|6,45|51,3|54,45|99,45|144,45|189,60|249,15|264,11|275,60| _`
  i have not checked those values, but it is close   1+5=6+45=51+3=54+45=99 .....

Comment: Thank you, @jsotola! That's fixed the import, though Excel still runs slowly. Can't believe I misinterpreted such a basic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Terms of Debugging the next step I would use is to try and work out *where* the code is crashing out. I usually write my On Error Statements so I can turn error trapping on and off i.e

instead of

```
 On Error GoTo EndOfFunction:
```

use

```
 If InDebugMode then On Error Goto EndOfFunction:
```

**InDebugMode** is just

```
 Public Const InDebugMode = True
```

That way the code will halt when something goes wrong and you can then use watches etc to then figure out what is happening (see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)